# Always execute code at beginning and end of method

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm connecting to MongoDb using following code :

```
   def insert() = {

    val mc = new com.mongodb.MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    val db = mc.getDatabase("MyDb");

    //My insert code

    mc.close();

  }                                               //> insert: ()Unit
```

I have various methods which open and close the connection.
  Can the lines :

```
  val mc = new com.mongodb.MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
val db = mc.getDatabase("MyDb");
mc.close();
```

be extracted so that they are implicitly called at beginning and end of method.
  Does Scala implicits cater for this scenario or is reflection required ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common pattern would be to use a call-by-name method where you can pass a function that accepts a `DB` and does something with it. The call-by-name method can facilitate the creation of the client, etc, and execute the code within.

```
def withDB[A](block: DB => A): A = {
  val mc = new com.mongodb.MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
  val db = mc.getDatabase("MyDb");
  try block(db) finally mc.close()
}
```

And use it:

```
def insert() = withDB { db =>
   // do something with `db`
}
```

However, a look at the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.0/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html) says:

> A MongoDB client with internal connection pooling. For most applications, you should have one MongoClient instance for the entire JVM.

Which makes the above approach look like a bad idea, assuming that is the version you are using. I can definitely see some concurrency issues trying to do this and having too many connections open.

But, you can follow the same pattern, stuffing the connection creating into a singleton object. You would need to manage the closing of the client when your application is shutdown, however.

```
object Mongo {
  lazy val mc = new com.mongodb.MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
  lazy val db = mc.getDatabase("MyDb");

  def withDB[A](block: DB => A): A = block(db)

  def close(): Unit = mc.close()
}
```

Comment: I doubt the last bit of code will work nicely as-is. Properly handling connection pools, initialization, clean-up is an involved process.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a method that executes some 'work' function e.g.

```
def withMongoDb[T](work: DB => T): T = {
  val mc = new com.mongodb.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
  // I don't actually know what type `db` is so I'm calling it `DB`
  val db: DB = mc.getDatabase("MyDb")

  try { work(db) }
  finally { mc.close() }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
withMongoDb { db =>
  db.insert(...)
  db.query(...)
}
```

This is a similar approach to the one used in [Slick, pre-3.0](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/connection.html#automatically-closing-session-scope), i.e. `withSession` and `withTransaction`.

Now, if you implemented some convenience methods e.g.

```
def insertStuff(values: Seq[Int])(implicit db: DB) = {
  db.insert(values)
}
```

Then you could call mark the `db` as implicit in your `withMongoDb` call, effectively making sure you never accidentally call `insertStuff` outside of that block.

```
withMongoDb { implicit db =>
  insertStuff(Seq(1,2,3,4))
}

insertStuff(Seq(1,2,3,4)) // compile error
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implicits you could do something like this:

```
  def mongoConn(ip:String, port:Int, dbName:String):(Database => Unit) => Unit  = {
    f => {
      val mc = new com.mongodb.MongoClient(ip, port)
      val db = mc.getDatabase(dbName)

      f(db)

      mc.close()
    }
  }

  val conn =  mongoConn("localhost", 27017, "MyDb")

  conn(db => {
    //insert code
  })
```